# set Date Picker Default Value to current day

Tags: android, datepicker

I built a date picker that will let the user chose the date and return it in such ("dd-MM-yyy");.  however, the date picker starts with 1990 year, I’m trying to change the default start date to the current day.

```
private void SetDatePicker() {
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listner = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
         currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
         currentday = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
         currentMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
         currentYear = new SimpleDateFormat("yy");

        todayDate = new Date();
        String thisDate = currentDate.format(todayDate);
        Log.w ("Date", thisDate);
        DateStore.set (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt (currentday.format(todayDate)));
        DateStore.set (Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt (currentMonth.format(todayDate)));
        DateStore.set (Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt (currentYear.format(todayDate)));


        DayofMonth =  DateStore.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        MonthOfMonth = DateStore.get (Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        mYear = DateStore.get (Calendar.YEAR);

        String DateString = String.valueOf (dayOfMonth) + "-" + String.valueOf (MonthOfMonth)  + "-" + String.valueOf (year);
        Log.w ("Date Test" , DateString);
    }
};
    DatePickerDialog DatePickerDioalg = new DatePickerDialog (getActivity() ,0,listner ,Integer.parseInt (currentday.format(todayDate)),
            Integer.parseInt (currentMonth.format(todayDate)),Integer.parseInt (currentYear.format(todayDate)));
DatePickerDioalg.show();
}
```

Here is the XML

```
                    <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext_date"
                    android:onclick="pickdate"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1.8"
                    android:background="#FFFF"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="10-09-2017"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this method for **date picker**

```
public void pickdate(View button) {
    // Get Current Date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    edittext_date.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

and this for **time picker**

```
public void picktime(View button) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // Launch Time Picker Dialog
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                      int minute) {

                    edittext_time.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                }
            }, mHour, mMinute, false);
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: I Tried Omar can you show me how to implement it, what to replace exactly. what is edittext_date

Comment: i added the xml originally it was a button but setText will not work with it. does this method work on a fragments

Comment: yes it will work on fragments , just add 'getcontext()' instead of 'this' for fragments, here """"TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getcontext(),
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() """"

Comment: ok i got them to show no errors but, im sorry one last thing the onClick method im not familiar with it usually i Tie them by id. this one is giving me Could not find method pickdate(View)

Comment: in that case just add code inside 'pickdate' and paste inside btn.setOnClicklistener() ,

Answer (score 0):

> You should try this one for getting current date:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                    String todate= dateFormat.format(currentdate());

String  finalto = todate.toString(); //here you get current date

private Date currentdate() {
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

Comment: app crash not working and what is currentdate() it not work

Comment: @Adnanhaider for getting current Date you can use new DateTime API from Java8.Ex: LocalDateTime.now();